# MySQL MATCH AGAINST fails to find 2-letter entries

Tags: mysql, indexing, match, full-text-search

MySQL 8.0.29.

So I've put the following in my configuration:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
```

Rebooted my server.

```
Rebuilt the Table Indexes with:
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And MATCH AGAINST still refuses to return records with 2-letter names, like "Ed Snow".

If I do MATCH AGAINST('ed') or AGAINST (+ed) OR (+ed snow) IN BOOLEAN MODE even though we have hundreds of people named "ed" in our databse... nothing comes up.

The column I'm matching against is a FULLTEXT name_full column like 'ed snow','ed smith', 'ed lindsky', etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any change in FTS settings needs in FT index rebuilding.

Comment: @Akina OK but I thought ALTER TABLE (as seen above) would do this. How do I rebuild a InnoDB index for a specific table with the latest version of MySQL? Was the above technique not correct?

Comment: There is only one method for to rebuild the index - drop and recreate it.

Comment: *I thought ALTER TABLE (as seen above) would do this.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length "Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes."

Comment: My mind is blown the only way to rebuild a FULLTEXT index is to drop it and recreate it; how on earth do DBAs rebuild FT indexes of hundreds of tables for large-scale databases? There's got to be another way other than dropping and recreating each individual index as once...

Comment: [Rebuilding or Repairing Tables or Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html). But these methods are more expensive than smple DROP/CREATE. *how on earth do DBAs rebuild FT indexes of hundreds of tables for large-scale databases?* Stored procedure which iterates over FTIs.

Comment: DBAs try to Plan Ahea

Comment: @Akina please post your answer. You are correct; the only way to do is to first set the two parameters and then drop and recreate the index.